# How to send existing email from shared mailbox to other email address using graph API c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

How to send existing email from inbox to other email address using graph API c#

I have tried sending the  existing email but Im not able to send it.
It is throwing error -Code: generalException Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service.

Below is the code snippet:

```
internal static async Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Message>> Sendemail(List<MM_Mailbox_Forward> toAddress, string smptpadd)
    {
        string from ="xyz@gmail.com"``your text``
        var Toptenmessages1 = graphClient.Users["xyz@gmail.com"].MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages.Request().Top(1);
        var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await Toptenmessages1.GetAsync());

        var authResult2 = task.Result;

        foreach (var message in authResult2)
        {
         try
            {
              var messages = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = message.Subject,
                        Body = message.Body,

                        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                        {
                             new Recipient
                                {
                                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                                    {
                                        Address = "abc@gmail.com"
                                    }
                                }
                        },
                    };
                  await graphClient
                    .Users[from]
                     .SendMail(messages, true)
                     .Request()
                     .PostAsync();
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error:" + ex);

            }
```

Comment: How you are not able to sent it? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? I think that some piece of code is missing. At least you can use `var topMessages = await Toptenmessages1.GetAsync();` instead of `var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await Toptenmessages1.GetAsync());var authResult2 = task.Result;`

Comment: Yes Im getting error message stating.....Code: generalException
Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service.

Comment: It would very much appreciated if you could send me the sample code to send the existing email from the inbox to another email address. I will try to change the code according to my project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using a shared email box, you can't (by default) send email with a shared email box.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm using shared mailbox only. Is there any chance to do that

Comment: I didn't tested it but it seems you can gon in your O365 admin panel > Users > Active users > Edit the main user (which is used to log in O365) > at right you can see a panel, select the Mail tab, you can see a link 'Send as permission'...